# Get Sum(Column) over (partition by other columns) with subset of partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning, window-functions

I need to make a sum of the count of all items in **"count2"** for the partitions, the screenshot below shows better than I could explain, but I need to sum the items in that column and then subtract them form the **"Lead2"** column
I have the following query:

```
SELECT td.EVENT_ID AS event_id, 
       td.MENU_HINT AS race, 
       td.EVENT_NAME AS event, 
       td.expr1003 AS [date], 
       td.raceno AS [race number],
       td.countwinnerprice5to8 AS [count1],
       td.sumwinnerprice5to8 AS [sum1],
       td.countwinnernotprice5to8 AS [count2],
       td.sumwinnernotprice5to8 AS [sum2],
       lead(td.sumwinnerprice5to8,1) OVER(PARTITION BY countwinnerprice5to8  Order by expr1003 desc, raceno desc, event_id desc ) as lead2,
       sum(td.countwinnernotprice5to8) OVER(PARTITION BY countwinnernotprice5to8  Order by expr1003 desc, raceno desc, event_id DESC rows between 1 following and unbounded following       ) as countlead2
FROM tbldata5 td
WHERE 
menu_hint LIKE '%Flem%'
ORDER BY expr1003 desc, raceno desc, event_id desc
```

which returns this table:

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════════════════════╦═════════════════╦════════════╦═════════════╦════════╦══════╦════════╦═══════╦═══════╦════════════╗
║  event_id ║ race                      ║ event           ║ date       ║ race number ║ count1 ║ sum1 ║ count2 ║ sum2  ║ lead2 ║ countlead2 ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 145719665 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 21st Jul ║ R9 1000m Hcap   ║ 2018-07-21 ║ 9           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 1      ║ 7.40  ║ NULL  ║ 1          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 145719663 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 21st Jul ║ R8 2000m Hcap   ║ 2018-07-21 ║ 8           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 0      ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║ 0          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 145719661 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 21st Jul ║ R7 1600m 3yo    ║ 2018-07-21 ║ 7           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 1      ║ 6.22  ║ NULL  ║ 2          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 145719659 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 21st Jul ║ R6 1100m 3yo    ║ 2018-07-21 ║ 6           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 1      ║ 7.60  ║ NULL  ║ 3          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 145719657 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 21st Jul ║ R5 1800m 2yo    ║ 2018-07-21 ║ 5           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 1      ║ 7.69  ║ NULL  ║ 4          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 145719655 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 21st Jul ║ R4 1200m Hcap   ║ 2018-07-21 ║ 4           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 1      ║ 5.90  ║ NULL  ║ 5          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 145719653 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 21st Jul ║ R3 2500m Hcap   ║ 2018-07-21 ║ 3           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 0      ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║ 0          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 145719651 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 21st Jul ║ R2 1700m Hcap   ║ 2018-07-21 ║ 2           ║ 1      ║ 6.67 ║ 1      ║ 6.56  ║ 8.00  ║ 6          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 145719649 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 21st Jul ║ R1 1400m 3yo    ║ 2018-07-21 ║ 1           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 0      ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║ 0          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 145210614 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 7th Jul  ║ R9 1200m Listed ║ 2018-07-07 ║ 9           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 1      ║ 5.26  ║ NULL  ║ 7          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 145210612 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 7th Jul  ║ R8 1600m Listed ║ 2018-07-07 ║ 8           ║ 1      ║ 8.00 ║ 2      ║ 15.42 ║ 5.64  ║ 2          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 145210610 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 7th Jul  ║ R7 1200m Listed ║ 2018-07-07 ║ 7           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 0      ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║ 0          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 145210608 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 7th Jul  ║ R6 2600m Hcap   ║ 2018-07-07 ║ 6           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 2      ║ 12.65 ║ NULL  ║ 4          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 145210606 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 7th Jul  ║ R5 1600m Listed ║ 2018-07-07 ║ 5           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 0      ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║ 0          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 145210604 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 7th Jul  ║ R4 1600m 3yo    ║ 2018-07-07 ║ 4           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 1      ║ 5.27  ║ NULL  ║ 8          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 145210602 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 7th Jul  ║ R3 1400m Hcap   ║ 2018-07-07 ║ 3           ║ 1      ║ 5.64 ║ 1      ║ 7.68  ║ 5.51  ║ 9          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 145210600 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 7th Jul  ║ R2 2000m Hcap   ║ 2018-07-07 ║ 2           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 0      ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║ 0          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 145210598 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 7th Jul  ║ R1 1600m 3yo    ║ 2018-07-07 ║ 1           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 3      ║ 21.97 ║ NULL  ║ 3          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 144827118 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 23rd Jun ║ R9 1100m Hcap   ║ 2018-06-23 ║ 9           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 1      ║ 5.33  ║ NULL  ║ 10         ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 144827116 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 23rd Jun ║ R8 1600m Hcap   ║ 2018-06-23 ║ 8           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 1      ║ 6.67  ║ NULL  ║ 11         ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 144827114 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 23rd Jun ║ R7 1400m Hcap   ║ 2018-06-23 ║ 7           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 0      ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║ 0          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 144827112 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 23rd Jun ║ R6 1600m 3yo    ║ 2018-06-23 ║ 6           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 2      ║ 13.03 ║ NULL  ║ 6          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 144827110 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 23rd Jun ║ R5 2520m Hcap   ║ 2018-06-23 ║ 5           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 2      ║ 14.56 ║ NULL  ║ 8          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 144827108 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 23rd Jun ║ R4 1400m Hcap   ║ 2018-06-23 ║ 4           ║ 1      ║ 5.51 ║ 3      ║ 20.44 ║ 7.80  ║ 6          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 144827106 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 23rd Jun ║ R3 1100m 3yo    ║ 2018-06-23 ║ 3           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 2      ║ 11.94 ║ NULL  ║ 10         ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 144827104 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 23rd Jun ║ R2 1400m Hcap   ║ 2018-06-23 ║ 2           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 1      ║ 7.29  ║ NULL  ║ 12         ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 144827102 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 23rd Jun ║ R1 1400m 2yo    ║ 2018-06-23 ║ 1           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 3      ║ 19.39 ║ NULL  ║ 9          ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 144506971 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 9th Jun  ║ R9 1000m 3yo    ║ 2018-06-09 ║ 9           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 1      ║ 7.97  ║ NULL  ║ 13         ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 144506969 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 9th Jun  ║ R8 2000m 3yo    ║ 2018-06-09 ║ 8           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 3      ║ 20.10 ║ NULL  ║ 12         ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 144506967 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 9th Jun  ║ R7 1400m Hcap   ║ 2018-06-09 ║ 7           ║ 0      ║ NULL ║ 1      ║ 5.71  ║ NULL  ║ 14         ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════════════════════╩═════════════════╩════════════╩═════════════╩════════╩══════╩════════╩═══════╩═══════╩════════════╝
```

The table is ordered by date/race number and event_id. this should be the final order of the table.

What I'm needing is to sum the count of every row in **count2** within the range between the **count1** items.

It might be easier to understand with graphic (click to enlarge).

[image]

So basically what I need to do is to summarize what is on the blue boxes and then subtract it to the not null row from **lead2** and add into **countlead2**. 
I can even handled it with temporal table or create a new column where to insert, so it can be cleaner and calculated later. but I don't know how to summarize the count of the blue box.

I've tried with combinations of **grouping sets**, and different combinations of sum over partitions. but I can't seem to be able to do what I need. I think partition by is the way to go.

So far I've tried with the 1 following and unbounded following to try to get the data I want, but it seems to go out of bounds. Is there a way to get the bound to be a variable? or to select the last following as the first of the next? And it seems that the preceding/following is not working with the partition I need.

Comment: Convention on SO is to include data as formatted text, not images.  You should also remove extraneous details from your question; there's no need for the columns that have nothing to do with your requirements.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question as well as https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you thought about storing you information in a temp table... or sub queries?

Comment: I could do it with temp tables, but how?  and Matt, the info is as text,. the image is to add more information as example, but the table has the minimal information required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to do it in multiple stages, rather than trying to do it all in a single SELECT statement.

```
WITH
  base AS
(
  -- your current query goes in here
),
  base_grouped AS
(
  -- First, create a group identifier, but in the -opposite- direction
  -- (This will group the rows where you want to sum [count2])
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM(count1) OVER (ORDER BY [date], [race_number], event_id)   AS group_id
  FROM
    base
),
  base_grouped_summed AS
(
  -- Then do the sum on [count2] within those groups
  SELECT
     *,
     SUM([count2]) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id)   AS sum_count2
  FROM
     base_grouped
)
-- Now deduct it from [lead2] (only does anything when [lead2] is not null)
SELECT
  *,
  lead2 - LAG(sum_count2) OVER (ORDER BY group_id)   AS new_value
FROM
  base_grouped_summed
```

If you know better ways to identify which rows to `SUM()`, you may be able to shorten this.  I just went with the most obvious rules based on your sample data.

***EDIT:***

To demonstrate what Common Table Expressions are, this is what the above code would look like with old-school nested sub-queries...

```
-- Now deduct it from [lead2] (only does anything when [lead2] is not null)
SELECT
  *,
  lead2 - LAG(sum_count2) OVER (ORDER BY group_id)   AS new_value
FROM
(
  -- Then do the sum on [count2] within those groups
  SELECT
     *,
     SUM([count2]) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id)   AS sum_count2
  FROM
  (
    -- First, create a group identifier, but in the -opposite- direction
    -- (This will group the rows where you want to sum [count2])
    SELECT
      *,
      SUM(count1) OVER (ORDER BY [date], [race_number], event_id)   AS group_id
    FROM
    (
      -- your current query goes here
    )
      AS base
  )
    AS base_grouped
)
  AS base_grouped_summed
```

Most people, once they get used to CTEs, find them much easier to read, modify and debug.

Comment: hey, this seems to get it :)  however is a bit big (I have to use it for 800 more columns :( )   I'll work on implementing it and come back

Comment: @Baldie47 - I'd hope they'd have commonalities, such as the the groups you're aggregating over.  That would mean that you're adding one line of code to each query, rather than adding multiple new queries...

Comment: commonalities? I've google it but I don't get it, this would work like a function? in my case I have a lot of more columns just like "count2" and "lead2" and I will need to apply a very the same calculations to them

Comment: @Baldie47 - The syntax above is named Common Table Expressions.  It's almost a drop in replacement for nested queries.  There's nothing stopping you adding even more columns to each level.  For example, you could add `SUM(count3) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) AS sum_count3` to the `summed` expression and then add `lead3 - LAG(sum_count3) OVER (ORDER BY group_id)` to the final query.  That assumes the definition for the `group_id` is still appropriate.  If not, you can also add `SUM(x) OVER (y) AS group_id_x` to the `grouped` expression.  You're just adding columns, not whole new expressions.

Comment: this does work @Mat, however it ends up being a HUGE piece of code, as I have to do this for 800 columns, and is 4 columns each, pretty unmanageable.  I'll create a new question with what I mean, maybe you will have a suggestion about how to make it a bit cleaner, I'll try to explain it better there

Comment: thank you very much Mat, your explanation was great. I have added a new question where I detail more what I'm dealing with, in case you would be able to suggest a solution there